# Deadlock trigger on MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, deadlock, galera

I can trigger a deadlock on our (test) Galera cluster when updating a row with the same data.

```
INSERT INTO test (id, val) VALUES (1, 42), (2, 47);
-- Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
-- Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Updating a value to a different value, doesn't result in an error:

```
UPDATE test SET val=43 WHERE id=1;
-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
-- Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

And when you set it to the same value:

```
UPDATE test SET val=47 WHERE id=2;
-- ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

It appears to be a sort of warning that is incorrectly relayed (from `/var/log/mysql`):

```
140106 13:52:04 [Warning] WSREP: SQL statement was ineffective, THD: 12, buf: 103
QUERY: UPDATE test SET val=47 WHERE id=2
 => Skipping replication
140106 13:52:04 [Warning] WSREP: SQL statement was ineffective, THD: 12, buf: 103
QUERY: UPDATE test SET val=47 WHERE id=2
 => Skipping replication
```

Note: the table is created like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
      `id` int(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      `val` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf-8;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your binary log format on the server is "STATEMENT" (Check by SELECT @@binlog_format;)
You should restart the server with --binlog-format=row and then retry your queries.
Normally this would fix your problem!

Source: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5490?jql=project%20%3D%20MDEV%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20text%20~%20%22update%20deadlock%22

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to update set the **mandatory settings** in the Galera cluster. Thanks!